# Visual Studio doesn't show SharePoint project option

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint

I have Sharepoint 2007 with Visual Studio 2005 along with OS Windows Server 2003.
Now I installed Visual Studio 2008. When I am trying to create a new project, Sharepoint option is not appearing. Do I need to change any settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint templates were built in first in VS 2010. For VS 2008 you would need to download and install [Visual Studio 2008 Extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=841) for SharePoint 2007 (Windows SharePoint Services 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Visual Studio 2008 has SharePoint templates built in. See here for more information and a download link of the templates http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pandrew/archive/2008/11/17/visual-studio-2008-extensions-for-sharepoint-project-templates-or-item-templates.aspx